# Is it possible to change the font-family of the hyphenation character in xsl-fo?

Tags: xsl-fo

I would like to use this character has my hyphenation character: `↵` (info on character at https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21b5/index.htm).

In my XSL code, I have:

```
<xsl:attribute name="hyphenate">true</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="hyphenation-character">↵</xsl:attribute>
```

But the character doesn't show up. I think it's because the font family I am using is Roboto Mono (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono), which doesn't have that character.

Is it possible to change the font family of just the hyphenation character? Or is it possible to specify an external graphic to be used as the hyphenation character?

I am using XEP to do my transformations.

Comment: Since you're using the return character and monospaced text, I'll assume that you're formatting some sort of code listing.  FYI, AH Formatter has a 'line continued mark' extension that's good for that.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-ext.html#line-continued-mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`font-family` can take a comma-separated sequence of font family names (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font-family).  You can put the name of a font that does have the `↵` character *after* 'Roboto Mono' in the `font-family` property and the formatter should try the second font when it finds that 'Roboto Mono' does not have the glyph.

It may be necessary to also set `font-selection-strategy="character-by-character"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font-selection-strategy) to force the font change for one character.

Comment: Works perfectly!